# How can I take a network buffer and pass it into a function that is expecting a FILE in C

Tags: c, buffer

I am looking to be able to download a file over a network socket from an HTTP server (A jpeg).  I then need to pass the downloaded file into c-jpeg-steganography http://code.google.com/p/c-jpeg-steganography/ .    I can use libcurl to download the file and then pass the filename into the library, but I would prefer to not do that if I don't have to.  Can I download the file and then pass it directly into c-jpeg-steganography easily?  Is there an easy way to modify the c-jpeg-steganography libraries to work?  Is the writing to a temporary file not a bad way to do this?

I am very much a C noob... please go easy.  Most of my experience is with languages that let me cheat and do all the work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The steganography site doesn't give the API details AFAICS, which is a nuisance.

<s>However, judging from your question, it appears that there is a steganographic function that takes an open `FILE *` (you never get to deal with `FILE`) which contains the unmodified image, and presumably the information you are trying to conceal in the image.  In that case, you can arrange to download the file via `libcurl` into an open file (which may not have a name); you can then rewind that `FILE *` and pass it to the steganography library.</s>

Having downloaded the library, the two main functions provided are:

#### steganolab_encode

```
/**
 * Modifies specified jpeg file so that it contains given message.
 * @param file - jpeg file name
 * @param data - message to embed
 * @param len - message length
 * @param password - key string to cipher data and set up PRNG
 * @param DCT_radius - which DCT coefficients shall be used to carry
 *      information, i^2+j^2 <= R^2
 * @param stats - pointer to structure to put statistics to. The caller
 * must take care about freeing the structure properly. NULL pass
 * disables statistics output.  The object don't need to be freed if the
 * function fails, and it contains no message.
 * @return              0: All OK
 *                              not 0: Failed
 **/
int steganolab_encode(const char * file, const char * data,
        unsigned int len, const char * password, uint8_t DCT_radius,
        struct steganolab_statistics * stats);
```

#### steganolab_decode

```
/**
 * Reads steganographic message from specified file
 * @param file - jpeg file name
 * @param data - pointer to pointer to string to put data to
 * @param len - pointer to push obtained buffer length to
 * @param password - secred string for cipher and PRNG
 * @param DCT_radius - which DCT coefficients shall be used to carry
 *      information, i^2+j^2 <= R^2
 * @param stats - statistics object. Free is up to the caller.
 * NULL disables the feature.  The object don't need to be freed if the
 * function fails, and it contains no message.
 * @return      0: All OK
 *                      not 0: fail (no buffers need freeing in this case)
 */
int steganolab_decode(const char * file, char ** data,
        unsigned int * len, const char * password, uint8_t DCT_radius,
        struct steganolab_statistics * stats);
```

Since the functions expect file names, you will have to provide file names.  Or you will have to rewrite the code to take whatever it is you have in mind - a buffer or an open file stream.

(Aside: the code insists on using the archaic and non-standard header `<malloc.h>` to obtain a definition of `size_t`.  It compiles to object if you replace each reference to `<malloc.h>` (or `"malloc.h"`) with `<stdlib.h>`; it might in theory compile with `<stddef.h>` if the only needed declaration is `size_t`.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to pretend that a memory buffer is a file so you really are limited to one of the two solutions you posit:

- write the information to a file then pass the file name to the library; or
- re-write the library to take an in-memory buffer.

I know the way I'd initially do it, that's the first option. That's the easiest way (as in quickest-to-market).

From examination of the source, the work involved in changing it to process memory rather than a file is non-trivial.

The `encode`, `decode` and `estimate` functions all call a single `worker` uber-function which receives the file name, opens it and, in turn, passes the file handle around quite a bit to other functions.

It's doable but the effort is substantially larger than just using a temporary file (although keep in mind it would only have to be done once, and the resultant code would then be available for all the world to use).

Comment: Thanks everyone.... I will look into fdopen.  That may work, if it doesn't then I will probably just write it out to a file.